# Access LevelDB with password

Tags: security, encryption, key-value-store, leveldb

Does LevelDB has option with password access to database? Or, if no, what is the analog, which I can encrypt db files and open them only with password?

Answer (score 1):

There [trousseau](https://github.com/oleiade/trousseau) that does that. It written in Go and use gpg to encrypt the leveldb database.

Here is an example use:

> $ trousseau --passhphrase mysupperdupperpassphrase get my-very-important-information

Comment: How to use is from go language?

Comment: I don't know have a look at the [ui](https://github.com/oleiade/trousseau/blob/master/trousseau.go).